# Groovy - Spock Data Table expected value

Tags: groovy, spock

I have a method for which I am writing unit tests using Spock. This method takes two strings as input and returns an integer value that can be 0, >0 and <0 based on some conditions in the methods (basically a string comparator). Now I want to use data tables to test this method but the problem is we don't know the specific value this method will return but just that it can will be greater or smaller in some scenarios. How to do assert that in Spock using data tables. I have already written individual tests for such cases but was wondering if this can be achieved.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is customary here to share sample code reproducing and illustrating your problem. In this case, please provide an example class under test and the Spock test itself, so the community can analyse code instead of prose.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to use data tables to test this method but the problem is
> we don't know the specific value this method will return but just that
> it can will be greater or smaller in some scenarios.

If you have a pair of inputs and you have an expectation that the return value of the MUT should be above or below some certain value, include that value in the data table and in your assertions assert that the return value relates to the data table value in the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Math.signum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum-double-) to compress your result down to (-1,0,1).
Then you can easily write your data table.

```
import spock.lang.*

class ASpec extends Specification {
  def "compare"() {
    expect: 
        Math.signum(comparator(a, b)) == result
      
    where:
        a | b || result
        1 | 2 || -1
        1 | 9 || -1
        1 | 1 || 0
        5 | 2 || 1    
        4 | 2 || -1 // fail intentionally
  }
    
    int comparator(int a, int b) {
        a - b
    }
}
```

[Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJxtkDEOwjAMRfec4oupRVAoggEkBg7AxAnckEJEmlRJECDau5MUKCDhxfov33ZsWdXGerja8FOmSB-yIWNckXPY7GrBIa5e6L1DFLKUnLw0GncG7EWJATdVTVYMkrRjCP5g9Ct0IsaW_DFz8qDPVfJ0kzc2oRGKNMV6DSvcWfmXv0uXo7Bi1XcgNCjQNL9OIA98Fvk4_2HLPyyPbNqjxbs074fGmH86YjJBSVJB6nCAuDQpdQvOlvUl4QlfK0UZ1oqpeJ_j-f8xik61rGUPLhxg4A)